# PL/SQL DB Deployment Script

Tags: oracle, plsql, sqlplus

I'm trying to write a deployment script to run with SQL*Plus in a CI/CD pipeline but I can't find my way around what seems to be a very basic issue.

Here's a shortened version of the script release.sql:

```
DECLARE
    vnum NUMBER;
BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(tname) INTO vnum FROM tab WHERE tname = 'DA_VERSION';
    IF vnum = 0 THEN -- run create scripts
        @ddl/da_001.sql
        @ddl/da_002.sql
        @dml/version.sql -- set initial version   
    END IF;
END;
```

da_001.sql looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE_NAME 
(
  COLUMN1 NUMBER NOT NULL 
, CONSTRAINT TABLE_NAME_PK PRIMARY KEY 
  (
    COLUMN1 
  )
  ENABLE 
);
```

When I run

```
sqlplus.exe connection_string @release.sql
```

I get

> CREATE TABLE DA_PRODUCTS
> *
> ERROR at line 6:
> ORA-06550: line 6, column 1:
> PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "CREATE" when expecting one of the following:...

So it doesn't like the CREATE statement at the beginning of da_001.sql but I don't know why. What am I missing here?

Comment: The PL/SQL language has no `CREATE` keyword. You'll need `execute immediate` or a different approach.

Comment: `@` is a `sqlplus` command, not a SQL or even PL/SQL command. It can **only**  be used on the `sqlplus` command line. PL/SQL code is run on the server without any notion about which client tool is used to call it or even access to the files on the client.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name if this is part of a SQL\*Plus script, though, SQL\*Plus will embed the referenced script in the PL/SQL block before executing it. The referenced scripts do have to be valid PL/SQL, though.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson: are you sure? This would require sqlplus to parse the PL/SQL body and replace the reference to the file with the actual file content before it sends the PL/SQL block to the server.

Comment: In the first script, you are missing the '/' at the end. Without this, it assumes the `CREATE TABLE` is part of teh PLSQL block.

Comment: Also, as other suggested, PLSQL does not understand SQLPLUS directives like `@` etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create an installation file for your scripts, ie

```
install.sql
===========
@ddl/da_001.sql
@ddl/da_002.sql
@dml/version.sql -- set initial version
```

and then selectively call it via a wrapper in SQL Plus

```
set feedback off
set pages 0
spool /tmp/runme.sql
select 
  case when COUNT(tname) = 0 then '@@install.sql' else 'pro Skipped install.sql' end
FROM tab WHERE tname = 'DA_VERSION';
spool off
@/tmp/runme.sql
```

Comment: This is perfect. I started adding EXECUTE IMMEDIATE to all of my DDL scripts and didn't like the smell.

Answer (score 1):

As others have said there is a strict separation between what SQL*PLus understands/is capable of and what is within the SQL and PLSQL languages.

Script handling is one of these distinct areas, which means you cannot executing a SQL script within a PLSQL block.

Also, SQL*Plus does not have any understanding of PLSQL logic constructs.

However, looking at your requirement there might be a way. The answer from @"Connor McDonald" should work. Here is my attempt using a more PLSQL based approach.

This approach uses SQL*PLus variables, which can be referenced and amended in both PLSQL and SQL*Plus.

First you need a 'No Op' script since when using the SQL*PLus '@' you must specify a valid script name:

noop.sql:

```
PROMPT No Op
```

Now your controller script:

```
-- Declare your variables 

VAR script1 VARCHAR2(256)
VAR script2 VARCHAR2(256)
VAR script3 VARCHAR2(256)

DECLARE
    vnum NUMBER;
BEGIN
    :script1 := 'noop.sql';
    :script2 := 'noop.sql';
    :script3 := 'noop.sql';
    SELECT COUNT(tname) INTO vnum FROM tab WHERE tname = 'DA_VERSION';
    IF vnum = 0 THEN -- run create scripts
         -- Set variables
        :script1 := 'ddl/da_001.sql';
        :script2 := 'ddl/da_002.sql';
        :script3 := 'dml/version.sql'; -- set initial version   
    END IF;
END;
/

-- Make variables referencable as SQLPLus defines

COLUMN s1 NEW_VALUE s1
COLUMN s2 NEW_VALUE s2
COLUMN s3 NEW_VALUE s3

SELECT :script1 s1, :script2 s2, :script3 s3
FROM dual;

-- RUN !!

@ &&s1
@ &&s2
@ &&s3
```

The 3 `scriptn` variables can be used in PLSQL.

To use as SQL_PLus substition variable (&) we use the `COL ... NEW_VALUE` command to map a  SELECT list column alias to a substituion variable. So we will effectively map `scriptn` to subs variabl;e `sn`.

After the PLSQL blocks completes the `scriptn` variables will have teh value 'noop.sql' or the name of teh script to run.

Then at the end, reference the subs variables in the '@' commands.

Anything with 'noop.sql' will execute a blank script.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used this myself but you might try something like this (simplified demo):

```
declare
    vnum number := 0;
begin
    --select count(tname) into vnum from tab where tname = 'DA_VERSION';
    if vnum = 0 then -- include create script
        execute immediate q'[
        @callthis.sql
        ]';
     end if;
end;
```

To work within `execute immediate`, the called script must contain a single statement and no semicolon.